# Utilizar google maps y pasar variables como longitud y latitud

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal donde una tabla se estara actualizando constantemento haciendo consultas a una base de datos de mysql, pero tambien estara desplegando un mapa con los ultimos datos obtenidos de la base de datos, es decir que la latitud y la longitud los obtendra de un array que recoge los datos, lo que no me funciona es que la funcion del mapa tome como referencia mis variables. Alguna idea ? Otra cosa, cuando hago un document write, me muestra perfectamente el numero.

```
function Cargar() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "consulta.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
 var array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 var titulo_ultimo = array[array.length - 1].titulo
 var latitud = array[array.length - 1].latitud
 var longitud = array[array.length - 1].longitud
 //document.write("Este es el ultimo titulo" + titulo_ultimo);
 var i;


 var ultimo = "<p class='' ></p>" + ("Este es el ultimo titulo " + longitud);
 if (titulo_ultimo == "vasodecoca") {
     alert("Hola");
 } 
 document.getElementById("ultimo").innerHTML = ultimo;

 var out = "<table border='1' class='table table-sm'>";
 for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 out+=" <tr><td>"+
 array[i].Id +
 "</td><td>"+
 array[i].titulo +
 "</td><td>" +
 array[i].descripcion+
 "</td><td>"+
 array[i].nombre+
 "</td></tr>";

 }

 out += "</table>";

 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = out;

 }


}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 

}
</script>
<style>
h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


</style>
<script>
function initMap() {
   latitud = parseFloat(latitud);
   longitud = parseFloat(longitud);
 // Creamos un objeto mapa y especificamos el elemento DOM donde se va a mostrar.
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
 center: {lat: latitud, lng: longitud},
 scrollwheel: false,
 zoom: 8
 });
}
</script>
<div id="mapa" style="width: 450px; height: 350px; margin-left: 20px;"> </div>
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo muy bien, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer con los puntos en el mapa? ¿quieres que el mapa se centre en el punto obtenido o lo que buscas es colocar marcadores en mapa con esos puntos?

Comment: Si, que el mapa muestre esas coordenadas y un marcador